# EF 6 Code First Query very slow

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an application that requires query to filter based on users selection. This query runs frequently. I am using code first. I need help to find a better way to perform this similar query. Right now this query takes 2 minutes to 5 minutes to execute. I have over 11K row.

```
var ads = from AllAds in _db.Rents
                      where (myStateId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressCommunities.RentAddressCities.RentAddressStates.RentAddressStateId == myStateId) : (myStateId == -1)
                      where (myCityId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressCommunities.RentAddressCities.RentAddressCityId == myCityId) : (myCityId == -1)
                      where (myPropertyTypeId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentPropertytypeId == myPropertyTypeId) : (myPropertyTypeId == -1)
                      where (myPropertyBedroomId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentBedroomtypeId == myPropertyBedroomId) : (myPropertyBedroomId == -1)
                      where (myPropertyBathroomId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentBathroomtypeId == myPropertyBathroomId) : (myPropertyBathroomId == -1)
                      where (MyCommunityId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressCommunities.RentAddressCommunityName == MyCommunityName) : (MyCommunityId == -1)
                      where (myStreetId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressStreetAddress == myStreetAddress) : (myStreetId == -1)
                      where (myPostalCodeId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressZipCode == myPostalCodeName) : (myPostalCodeId == -1)
                      where (myMonthlyRentId == 500) ? (AllAds.RentRent <= 499) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 700) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 500 && AllAds.RentRent <= 699) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 900) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 700 && AllAds.RentRent <= 899) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 1200) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 900 && AllAds.RentRent <= 1199) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 1500) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 1200 && AllAds.RentRent <= 1499) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 2000) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 1500 && AllAds.RentRent <= 1999) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 2500) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 2000 && AllAds.RentRent <= 2499) :
                       (myMonthlyRentId == 50000) ? (AllAds.RentRent >= 2500) : (myMonthlyRentId == -1)
                      where (mySquareFeetId == 700) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet <= 699) :
                      (mySquareFeetId == 900) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet >= 700 && AllAds.RentSquareFeet <= 899) :
                      (mySquareFeetId == 1200) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet >= 900 && AllAds.RentSquareFeet <= 1199) :
                      (mySquareFeetId == 1500) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet >= 1200 && AllAds.RentSquareFeet <= 1499) :
                      (mySquareFeetId == 2000) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet >= 1500 && AllAds.RentSquareFeet <= 1999) :
                      (mySquareFeetId == 2500) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet >= 2000 && AllAds.RentSquareFeet <= 2499) :
                      (mySquareFeetId == 50000) ? (AllAds.RentSquareFeet >= 2500) : (mySquareFeetId == -1)
                      orderby AllAds.dateCrawled descending, AllAds.dateListed descending
                      select AllAds;
            return ads.ToList<Rent>().AsQueryable();
```

In this example, if user selects any city then this query will perform with the city name and will filter based on this line. Other filters in where clause will be ignored.

```
where (myCityId > 0) ? (AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressCommunities.RentAddressCities.RentAddressCityId == myCityId) : (myCityId == -1)
```

I am saving this query in memory so that if user selects Propertytype, the query will perform only on the previous filtered result. This way any subsequent query takes minimal time. However the initial query takes too long.

Any suggestion please!! What would be the better approach to perform this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Compose the query!

All these conditions make it virtually impossible for the query optimizer to calculate a good query plan. Most of the time, only a few conditions will be entered but still all other predicates are part of the query. They will simply evaluate to true or false, but the problem is that there are so many of them and the number of possible optimizations grows exponentially. As is said [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery%28en-us%29.aspx):

> For complex queries, the number of all possible permutations can be huge, so the query optimizer does not evaluate all possibilities but instead tries to find a plan that is "good enough" for a given query. This is because finding a perfect plan may not always be possible; and even when it is possible, the cost of evaluating all the possibilities to find the perfect plan could easily outweigh any performance gains.

So if you reduce the number of predicates there is a better chance that the query optimizer finds a good execution plan.

The general approach to do this is

```
if (myStateId > 0)
{
    rents = rents
           .Where(AllAds => AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressCommunities
                                  .RentAddressCities.RentAddressStates
                                  .RentAddressStateId == myStateId);
}
if (myCityId > 0)
{
    rents = rents
           .Where(AllAds => AllAds.RentAddresses.RentAddressCommunities
                                  .RentAddressCities
                                  .RentAddressCityId == myCityId);
}
if ...
```

You get the idea.

You can also compose a query by using a predicate builder like [Linqkit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

The idea is that only the predicates that matter will be part of the query. This not only reduces the number of execution paths the query optimizer has to crunch but also saves you a number of costly joins if predicates involving joins will not be entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure, make sure you have appropriate indexes, and run the query using the stored proc rather than through EF expressions. It will perform *much* better.

You can still access the stored procedure through EF by linking to it in your .edmx.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896334%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Or you could call the stored proc using .SqlQuery:
    return _db.Database.SqlQuery("exec DB_SP_FIND_MATCHING_RENTS @stateId @cityId",stateId, cityId);

More info on .SqlQuery
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx